# How can I have two modules interact with each other without having a circular import on Python?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I am making a small game with several files including :

Entity.py , Map.py.

I want Map to be able to manage an Entity position, so I have to import Entity in Map, but I also want Entity to be able to know the map on which it is, so I have to import Map in Entity.

Obviously this leads to circular imports, and I know a lot of answers to this problem is "You just have to modify your design pattern" and ofc I could do that, but I want to know if there is a way in python to have this kind of structure that I got used to be able to use in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may work for you:

a.py:

```
import b

def a_func():
    print("a_func() called")
b.a_func = a_func

a_func()
b.b_func()
b.a_func()
```

b.py:

```
a_func = None

def b_func():
    print("b_func() called")
```

No output from:

```
 $ python b.py
```

Output from:

```
 $ python a.py
a_func() called
b_func() called
a_func() called
```

Lots of variations on the theme. Hope this helps.